# How to make rvmrc file in project root folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I have just installed RVM in my machine and facing problem with rvmrc file, can anyone help me out, how to create rvmrc?

I just did:

```
rvmrc --create ruby-1.8.7-p352@gemset
```

but didn't get the result...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It seems that there is a small mistake. Inside your `.rvmrc` file add:

```
rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p352@gemset --create
```

Also you might want to change the name of your gemset to something that is a bit more intuitive to read :)

**UPDATE**

Using the rvmrc file has now been deemed deprecated. Instead a .ruby-version file with the ruby version e.g. '2.0.0' and a .ruby-gemset file with the gemset name e.g. 'monkeys_of_doom'

This way developers using other version managers such as rbenv can pick up the ruby version in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 23):

```
rvm --rvmrc --create ruby-1.8.7-p352@gemset
```

Read this article. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-use-rvm/

Answer (score 12):

If the gemset already exists, it is sufficent to add `rvm ruby-1.8.7-p352@gemset` to the `.rvmrc` file, which can be achieve for instance by

```
echo "rvm ruby-1.8.7-p352@gemset" > .rvmrc
```

UPDATE: it looks like the .rvmrc file format is deprecated, and the usage of `.ruby-gemset` and `.ruby-version` files is encouraged instead. If "rails2.3.5" is your gemset name, then one would require the following two commands

```
echo "ruby-1.8.7-p352" > .ruby-version
echo "rails2.3.5" > .ruby-gemset
```

Answer (score 10):

I found working solution (http://sirupsen.com/get-started-right-with-rvm/)

```
rvm --create --rvmrc 1.8.7@project
```

Comment: Out of the above examples this one worked for me. I'm using fish shell so it's possible my commands are not 1:1 with bash

Answer (score 7):

you can also do this

```
rvm --rvmrc --create use ruby-1.9.3-p194@myproject
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `rvmc` use:

```
rvm --create --ruby-version ruby-2.1.04@my-project
```

will generates the `.ruby-gemset` and `.ruby-version` files

Answer (score 3):

here is another much simpler approach

```
rvm use 1.8.7@gemset --create
```

Answer (score 3):

The definitive documentation is at https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/ for how to create rvmrc files, and the global .rvmrc parameters that affect them.

The --rvmrc parameter is what actually creates the rvmrc files, then you have to run

> rvm rvmrc trust .

in the project directory to generate, and record, the security md5 hash to use that rvmrc file. The command 'trusts' the file so you're not prompted to trust it every time you enter the directory.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to create a rvmrc like -

```
rvm --rvmrc --create  use ruby-2.2.1@gemset_name
```

Then run

`rvm rvmrc trust .`

That will resolve the issue for selecting rvm for differnt application.

Hope you enjoy. :)

Answer (score 1):

For creating rvmrc file with specific ruby and gemset then use below command -

```
rvm --rvmrc --create ruby-with-version@gemset_name
```

like:

```
rvm --rvmrc --create ruby-2.3.3@rails5
```

Now we should need to select project location for change reflection so type **cd ..** and **hit enter** in terminal

Again type **cd project_name/** for selecting our project but now you get *** Notices** something like below image so here you just type **y** and **hit enter**.

[image]

Now you have successfully created rvmrc file so from now no need to select gemset each time on selecting different projects.