# Gem path error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails.

I have an issue when I try to run the app.  I get the following errror:

> *** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p174@soda/ruby: No such file or directory (2)

This is true; there is no such directory.  There is a file called 
`/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p174@DACE/ruby` - which is exactly the gem file I want to use.

As I understand it, the `.rvmrc` file specifies the directory for the gem file.  In this case, however, the `.rvmrc` has the following:

```
rvm --create use  "ruby-1.8.7-p174@DACE"
```

Furthermore, `rvm info` statues that `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@DACE` is in fact the gem path.

So, why does it think it should be looking for this non-existant path?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: What's the output of: `which rvm`, `rvm current`, and `rvm gemset list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a `rvm current` to see which version of ruby and which gemset you are using. Then run `rvm gemset list` to see which gemsets do you have created. If `soda` is not listed, then do a `rvm gemset create soda` to create this gemset.
Remove this `.rvmrc` file and then create another one. (This won't break anything on your project, just the project reference of ruby and gems would be deleted).
You can read this answer to help you understand better how rvm works, there is a link there:

[How to make rvmrc file in project root folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138376/how-to-make-rvmrc-file-in-project-root-folder/11138494#11138494)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while setting up rails production machine with Nginx & Passenger. Here's how I solved the problem.

1. Make sure passenger gem is installed then cd into project directory and run the following command

> ```
> passenger-config build-native-support --help
> ```

Which will give you output similar to following:

> Usage: passenger-config build-native-support [OPTIONS]
>
> Phusion Passenger utilizes a Ruby native extension, called
>   native_support,   for improving Ruby performance. The extension
>   depends on the   Phusion Passenger version and the Ruby version.
>   Normally, every time you run   a Phusion Passenger version with a Ruby
>   version that it hasn't encountered   before, it will rebuild the
>   native_support library for that Ruby version.   By running this
>   command, you can force the native_support to be built for   the
>   current Ruby interpreter.
>
> The current Ruby interpreter is:
>
> ```
> Path: /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-x.x.x@gemset/wrappers/ruby
> Version: 2.1.5
> ```
>
> Options:
>       -h, --help                       Show this help

2. Now copy the Path from output and paste it into nginx configuration file. In my case it was located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

   passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-x.x.x@gemset/wrappers/ruby
3. And finally restart the server or run your deployment script.