# rvm .rvmrc file generation impossible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, rvmsudo

I have created a rails3 app using rvm a few month ago. Everything works fine.

Now, I want to create another rails3 app. So I done :

```
$> rails new my_app
```

Everything works fine. Next, I wanted to link my app with rvm, so I tryed this:

```
$> ruby -v
   ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]
$> rvm install 1.9.3
$> rvm get head
$> rvm --rvmrc --create 1.9.3-p448@my_app (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138376/how-to-make-rvmrc-file-in-project-root-folder)
```

But I have got this error :

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@bcayi': Permission denied
```

Ok, permission denied, so I tryed:

```
$> rvmsudo --rvmrc --create 1.9.3-p448@my_app
```

And I have got this error:

```
sudo: invalid option -- '-'
```

So my question is : How to link rvm to my rails app ?

Comment: Getting the sudo invalid option error as well with Scientific Linux 6.4 (x86_64) and latest stable RVM as of this writing. In my case it turned out that - provided I was in the `rvm` group - I didn't even have to use `rvmsudo` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !

Because the `rvmsudo --rvmrc --create 1.9.3-p448@my_app` failed, I have created the 1.9.3-p448@my_app directory manually :

```
$> sudo mkdir /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@my_app
```

Then, I passed the ruby-1.9.3-p448@my_app directory in the rvm group :

```
$> sudo chown jeremy:rvm /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@my_app
$> sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@my_app
```

Finally, I could create my gemset without `rvmsudo` :

```
$> cd my_app/
$> rvm gemset create my_app
$> rvm --rvmrc --create ruby-1.9.3-p448@my_app
$> cd .. ; cd my_app/
   You are using '.rvmrc' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

because your RVM is installed in system (`/usr/local/rvm` vs. `$HOME/.rvm`) you need to be in `rvm` group (check with `id`) to be able to do things with rvm (like creating gemsets in this case).

To add yourself to `rvm` group run:

```
rvm group add rvm $USER
```

then you might need to restart your console / computer to make it work properly - sometimes OSX after freshly adding you to group will report it in `id` but it will be not effective till restart of computer (or relogin, but on OSX it's the same time).

Comment: I'm already in rvm group: `$> rvmsudo rvm group add rvm $USER ` tells me : `User 'jeremy' already in the group 'rvm'`

Comment: what does running `id` tell you? if it's not in `rvm` group - did you restart computer?

Comment: @mpapis: Thanks, although my user was already in the `rvm` group, your answer provided the context to understand that I needn't use `rvmsudo` at all to manipulate a system RVM instance, as long as I'm in that group. Also thanks for RVM!

Answer (score -1):

try

```
sudo rvm --rvmrc --create 1.9.3-p448@my_app
```

Comment: downvoted, you have clearly no idea how rvm works - it's a shell function that changes current process environment, prefixing it with `sudo` changes the process and runs it as binary.

Comment: fair enough.  that's a good description of rvm and worth the downvote